# intellij shortcut 'Add selection for next occurence' in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, shortcut

i find very useful the  intellij shortcut 'Add selection for next occurence'.It basically adds to the current selection the next occurence of the same selected text,allowing so to modify a lot of same occurences at once and at your choosing(and not just all the occurences).
Now i've switched to eclipse to develop in php(and more),and i would like this shotcut back, but i cannot find it.I found the one that gets all the occurences(the name is 'Add all matches to multi selection'),but not the one who just gets the next one.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, the command to add the next occurrence to multi-selection is called ***Multi selection down relative to anchor selection***.

**By default**, there is **no shortcut** for this command, so you have to add a key binding yourself in the preferences *General > Keys* (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice), e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (which would be similar to *Find Next* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

See also:

- [Eclipse 4.24 - New and Noteworthy - Action commands for multiple carets/selections](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.24/platform.php#multi-select-commands)
- [My *Eclipse 2022-06 Java IDE Improvements* video at 8:46](https://youtu.be/zDJtVYAJwyY?t=526)

Comment: thanks for the answer.Somehow though the two short cuts are not the same.In eclipse in does hightlight the next occurence just one time,after the it highlights all the text between.Maybe there shortcut (the alt+j in intellij )avalaible in eclipse.

Comment: For me, Eclipse's _Multi selection down relative to anchor selection_ does the same as [IntellIJ's _Select multiple occurrences of a word or a text range_](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html#multiple_words). Could you please give an example of where they differ?

Comment: it just doesn t work for me.I've seen your links and eclipse and the shortcut Multi selection down relative to anchor selection should be like how it is in intellij with the default alt+j.When i try it in  eclipse(linux ubuntu) though it highlights the next occurence one time(as expected), at the second shortcut input,it highlights all the text between the two occurences(including the two occurences) and not the third occurence.

Comment: Maybe you have a key binding conflict. Try to run the command via _Find Action_ (Ctrl+3). Please provide an example to reproduce what you see in the simple _Text Editor_ of Eclipse to be sure it is nothing editor specific.

Comment: I dont think there is a binding conflict(i will check).Anyway for the example,just think of a normal setter of a property.It takes the first occurence(from the parameter,the property) but it doesnt select the parameter with it is assigned to the property.Instead,it selects the everything between the first two occurences.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you say. For me the command behaves exactly the same in Eclipse as described in the [IntellIJ's documentation by the animated GIF](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html#multiple_words). Make sure in the preferences _General > Keys_ in the section _Show key binding when command is invoked_ both options are enabled, to see which command is being executed. It's up to you to provide an example of where it doesn't work.